# How do I prove 8(x)! + (2x-1)² where x is an integer greater than or equal to 3, is never a perfect square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, square-numbers

$8(x)! + (2x-1)^2 = a^2$, so $8(x)! = a^2-(2x-1)^2$, for $x \geq 8$, $64|\text{LHS}$, but we can see 8 doesn't divide both of $(a-2x+1)(a+2x-1)$, so 64|one of them, so both one of them is $0 \pmod {64}$ and thus $0 \pmod{8}$, so $(a+1)$ and $(a-1)= 0\pmod8$, so $a= \pm1 \pmod8$, please solve it or hint further:)

Comment: When you say $8x!$, do you mean $(8x)!$ or $8(x!)$? Also, your title says $(2x-1)$ while your question body says $(2x-1)^2$.

Comment: The title doesn't match the question here. Do you mean $(2x-1)^2$?

Comment: Though the question is a little confusing, you can use the stronger $x \geq 4$ instead of using $x \geq 8$

Comment: Hello, it's edited, check once again please!

Comment: Upto $x=10^5$ ,  perfect squares occur only for $x=0,1,2$. No idea for a proof of the claim.